# C# Sockets Receive Method Does not Receive Data

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy

I am having an odd problem and need someone's help.  I have a program that acts as part of a proxy chain.  It takes in data from one thing and sends it to another.  The only problem I am having is that the receive method takes in nothing.  It just freezes there.  My program:

Let's say we have four nodes in the chain: A, B, C, and D.

A is a web browser

B is my C# program

C is my C# client

D is a website

B is listening for *both* C and A.  Very weird, I know, but that's how I need it configured.  How can I get this damn program to work?  I already have a good amount of code set up, but for some reason, C is not receiving anything from B.  C connects to B all right, but C will not receive anything.  Can anyone help me?

I have all of my ports opened, my firewall is off for both B and C.  A and B are both running on my local machine.  To give you some IPs:

A connects to 127.0.0.1:3056

B listens for 127.0.0.1:3056 and B listens for IPAddress.Any:3055

C connects to MY_IP_ADDRESS:3055 and C connects to wherever B tells it

where MY_IP_ADDRESS is my global IP address taken from whatismyip.com

Why isn't C receiving anything?  Here is some surrounding code:

Client (C):

```
Socket reqSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("MY_IP_ADDRESS"), 3055);
reqSocket.Connect(ip);
byte[] ReqData = new byte[8192];
MessageBox.Show("BYTE"); // This runs, (click OK)
reqSocket.Receive(ReqData);
String ReqString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReqData);
MessageBox.Show(ReqString); // This does not
```

Server (B):

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3056);
listener.Start();
Socket Localhost = listener.AcceptSocket();
listener.Stop();
TcpListener listener2 = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3055);
listener2.Start(50);
Socket toSocket = listener2.AcceptSocket();
listener2.Stop();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
Localhost.Receive(buf);
toSocket.Send(buf);
MessageBox.Show("Sent!"); // This runs
```

These are both indeed open at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both client and server are making a call to `Receive` at the start. So both client and server are going to block until they can return either *at least* one byte, or report an EOF. Since both are waiting for incoming data, neither actually ever gets around to sending anything. So: deadlock.

Also: both of the calls to `Receive` fail to capture the return value which *tells you how much data was read* - this is a big error. In particular, you can't decode with a multi-byte encoding (like UTF-8) if you can't even guarantee tht you have a full number of characters - technically you could have two-and-one-third characters from a 50 character sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  Could I set Blocking = false?

Comment: @user1951033 no; Receive is fundamentally a blocking call - it blocks until it can return either an EOF or at least one byte (assuming timeouts aren't in play, and tht isn't a great idea). Now, doing a BeginReceive or ReceiveAsync might make sense.